# How to pass a string as an argument?

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a line of code as:

```
y="WIN_"+x[0:4]+x[5:7]+x[8:10]+"_"+x[11:13]+"_"+x[14:16]+"_"+x[17:19]+"_"+"Pro.jpg"
```

`print y` gives a long string i.e. `WIN_20170910_23_27_11_Pro.jpg`

Now i have next line of code as

```
img_url ='y'
result = CF.face.detect(img_url)
```

But it shows invalid img_url

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around y in your line:
img_url = y

You might have other issues with finding the img ("prefixing img_url with './' to mean the current directory can sometimes help")